# Domino-designer-Eclipse does not recognize classes from jar-files in java design elements

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

This is utterly annoying but perhaps not a deal breaker. When I add jar-files, under code->Jars (especially large ones) often the java editor does not recognize the classes when I edit java design elements. After making several cleans, closing/opening the database and poking around with the java build paths, they (the jar files) gets accepted. This does NOT affect whether or not the class is built, that works fine, but it f**** up all the type ahead. I'm doing the dev over a vpn and that might have an effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection to the server via VPN may have an impact on this, but mostly the workspace folder is corrupt so you should clean it up (just test it by renaming it and then restart DDE again). If this then occurs again, remove the new workspace folder and rename the original one back, especially if you have extra plugins installed so that they won't get lost.
What about using a local (on local server) copy/replica of your application to avoid network issues?